# Javascript array display buttons on each click

Tags: javascript, arrays

HTML and JS....I need the array values to be displayed one by one on each click of the "create new button" button. Right now when I click it displays each button in the array???

```
<div class="container">
    <button onClick="myPar()">Directions</button>
    <button onClick="make()">Create New Button</button>
</div>

<script>
  function myPar() {
    var pgp = document.createElement("p");

    var txt = document.createTextNode('Click on the "Create New Button" to reveal up to 10 links!!!');

    pgp.appendChild(txt);

    document.body.appendChild(pgp);
  }

  function make(){
    sit = new Array("kilroerock.com","ultimateguitar.com","premierguitar.com","jhspedals.com","sweetwater.com","guitarcenter.com","musiciansfriend.com","patriots.com","bostonceltics.com")

    for (i=0;i<=sit.length-1;i++){
      var btn = document.createElement("input");

      btn.setAttribute("value",sit[i]);

      btn.setAttribute("type","button");

      btn.setAttribute("style","background:#1B0D0D;color:white");

      btn.setAttribute("onClick","document.location='http://www." + sit[i] + "'")

      document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the whole array on every click. Instead of the `for` loop just hold a `currentIndex` variable outside of the function, then on each click get the `sit[currentIndex]`, use it per your need and afterwards raise the `currentIndex` by 1.

```
var currentIndex = 0;
sit = new Array("kilroerock.com","ultimateguitar.com","premierguitar.com","jhspedals.com","sweetwater.com","guitarcenter.com","musiciansfriend.com","patriots.com","bostonceltics.com")

function make(){
    if ( currentIndex < sit.length )
    {
        var btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.setAttribute("value",sit[currentIndex]);
        btn.setAttribute("type","button");
        btn.setAttribute("style","background:#1B0D0D;color:white");
        btn.setAttribute("onClick","document.location='http://www." + sit[currentIndex] + "'")
        document.body.appendChild(btn);      

        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/JbLNBa?editors=1111).

Comment: @cale_b then before accessing the array, check the `currentIndex ` against the `sit.length`.

Comment: @cale_b added the condition to avoid the error. Also updated the code example in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest route based on your existing code is to implement a "counter".

```js
// Initialize the counter outside of all functions, set to zero
var buttonIndex = 0;

function myPar() {
  var pgp = document.createElement("p");

  var txt = document.createTextNode('Click on the "Create New Button" to reveal up to 10 links!!!');

  pgp.appendChild(txt);

  document.body.appendChild(pgp);
}

function make() {
  sit = new Array("kilroerock.com", "ultimateguitar.com", "premierguitar.com", "jhspedals.com", "sweetwater.com", "guitarcenter.com", "musiciansfriend.com", "patriots.com", "bostonceltics.com")

  // Only add the button if within the array length
  if (buttonIndex < sit.length) {
    var btn = document.createElement("input");

    // Modify this line to use buttonIndex, not i
    btn.setAttribute("value", sit[buttonIndex]);

    btn.setAttribute("type", "button");

    btn.setAttribute("style", "background:#1B0D0D;color:white");

    // Modify this line to use buttonIndex, not i
    btn.setAttribute("onClick", "document.location='http://www." + sit[buttonIndex] + "'")

    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    // Increment the buttonIndex
    buttonIndex++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onClick="myPar()">Directions</button>
  <button onClick="make()">Create New Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this
Here s working example
https://plnkr.co/edit/juTx9sEZ4PhAoDrb2uHM?p=preview

```
function buttonClick(){
  var length = sit.length;

        if(i<length){
        var btn = document.createElement("input");

        btn.setAttribute("value",sit[i]);

        btn.setAttribute("type","button");

        btn.setAttribute("style","background:#1B0D0D;color:white");

        btn.setAttribute("onClick","document.location='http://www." + sit[i] + "'")


        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        i++;}
}
```